# Screwed up PATH in ~/.bash_profile, now cannot edit it

Tags: bash, vim, emacs, .bash-profile

I actually screwed up the `$PATH` variable in my `~/.bash_profile` while installing some software. Instead of using

```
export PATH=$PATH:/some/other/path
```

I idiotically did this

```
export PATH=~/some/other/path
```

So, no I cannot use any commands. If I try `ls`, I get this;

```
 $ ls
bash: ls: command not found...
Similar command is: 'lz'
```

How can I edit my `~/.bash_profile` to fix this mess? I cannot use vim or emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/bin/nano ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
/usr/bin/emacs ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
/usr/bin/vim ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the full path to emacs or vim. ie.

```
/bin/vim .bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

for Anaconda 3

```
$ /usr/bin/vim ~/.bashrc

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda3/bin
```

[image]

Then <kbd>Esc</kbd> button

```
:wq
```

to save and exit vim editor
then type

```
$ export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

to confirm the version installed

```
$ conda --version
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `vim`, `emacs` or `nano` then just go with your favourite editor and edit your `bash_profile` which is located in your home directory.

```
atom ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
subl ~/.bash_profile
```

And then just edit whatever you want at the bottom.

Comment: Did you miss the part of the question where the OP said "I cannot use any commands"?